# slideshow using touch sequence for the next image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in xcode just doing the transition. set of image in the nsarray,like slide show. have to change the image using transition  for right to left using touch

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to describe your question briefly.You can use Page control for that.It may be more useful to you.
You can get sample code in below link "http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html"

Answer (score 0):

use the leftswiping gestures and right swiping gestures.